# Can fake hawks be used to control mice, squirrels, and other rodents in a garden or backyard? 

Tags: pest-control, rodents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get rid of gophers in a non-lethal way?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/148/how-can-i-get-rid-of-gophers-in-a-non-lethal-way)
>   [Keeping mockingbirds off potted plants (ornamental peppers)](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/keeping-mockingbirds-off-potted-plants-ornamental-peppers)
>   [How can I prevent squirrels (or other small mammals) from eating my tomatoes?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-i-prevent-squirrels-or-other-small-mammals-from-eating-my-tomatoes)
>   [How can I get rid of rabbits in my yard?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/140/how-can-i-get-rid-of-rabbits-in-my-yard) 
>   [Is there any way to prevent vole lawn-destruction during snow-cover?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/150/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-vole-lawn-destruction-during-snow-cover)

Can fake hawks be used to control mice,squirrels, and other rodents in a garden or backyard? Would an electronic hawk that made hawk-like noises fare any better?

If these "fake hawks" do not work, are there any humane alternatives which act as simple deterrents?