# How can I prevent my neigbour's cat from marking its territory in my garden?

Tags: pest-control, domestic-animals

We have various bits of garden furniture and this is the kind of furniture that can be left out.  Our neighbour has a male neutered cat that sprays literally everything, including our conservatory and now the garden furniture.

What can we do to stop this happening?  Is there a way to stop cats marking their territory or put them off?

We don't want to harm the cat in any way.

Comment: Is this a male unspayed cat?

Comment: It is a male, but he has been neutered, a very beautiful siamese cat, looks just like an egyptian statue.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds a contradiction. A Siamese cat in Egypt :) I'd be asking the neighbors to keep their cat inside though. Domestic and feral cats kill too many birds.

Comment: We live in the UK, what I meant was he looks like an Egyptian Statue, perfect shape.  I don't think keeping him inside is an option.

Comment: Related: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-you-safely-and-effectively-stop-a-cat-from-pooping-in-your-yard

Comment: Unless you've actually seen your neighbor's cat doing it don't necessarily assume it was their cat or only their cat. Most neighborhoods have some sort of feral cat population that you may not necessarily see. After setting up different security devices I was surprised how many random cats would pass through.

Comment: I have seen it many many times, its not shy.

Comment: I don't think its fair to keep a cat inside, glad you don't expect that...

Comment: I love cats and this cat, I just want it to stop spraying everything.

Answer (score 4):

The most effective method is a sprinkler linked to a movement detector which turns on when it detects movement in the area, and stops  when movement ceases. There are several available at various prices (Amazon has a range) and they're sold as motion detector sprinklers. Link below is to Amazon in the UK

https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=motion+sprinkler&tag=googhydr-21&index=aps&hvadid=28710841568&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=4894428948365043153&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=t&ref=pd_sl_mc7s0y2h5_b

It sounds as if the cat next door is a tom, and likely it's un-neutered - if the owners ever get it neutered, you won't have so much of a problem. Although some male cats continue to spray after the surgery, the rank scent associated with it will be gone.

Comment: As I can observe regularly: neutered male cats do spray. Especially if there are squabbles about territory and rank.

Comment: @Stephie - yep, they do - but it doesn't reek in the same way! Even one of my female cats used to do a bit of spraying...or go through the motions at least.

Comment: It always seems that a cat won't mark its territory in its own back garden but will in everyone else's.

Comment: @SPlatten - they do also mark their own gardens, specially at the boundaries, but tom cats do it all over the place, like a calling card as much as anything

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. You can put little plastic containers of cinnamon where the cats go. They don't like the smell. Make sure the containers are small and have tiny holes so the odor escapes. Change the cinnamon after 2-3 rains.

Containers should minimize spillage.

You can also take potted plants, sprinkle the dirt in them with cinnamon, and place those around the sprayed area.